# how to exclude file only in root directory using git?

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore file `init.js` that is inside root directory but not inside `lib/apps/<DIR>/` directories, how can I do this?

I've tried:

```
./init.js
```

but this don't work.

Comment: Have you tried `/init.js`?

Comment: @SevenEleven yes it works, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @SevenEleven suggested in a comment, `/init.js` (without the leading dot) works.